# How does a linux block driver ensure all I/O has finished before unloading

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, block-device

A linux block device driver allocates a `struct gendisk` and any associated metdata, and provides a queue or some implementation of the `submit_bio` function to handle incoming `I/O` requests from the operating system.

When a disk is being removed, it calls:

```
del_gendisk(brd->brd_disk);
blk_cleanup_disk(brd->brd_disk);
...
kfree(brd);
```

see for example, the `brd_cleanup` routine for the [ramdisk driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.19/source/drivers/block/brd.c).

How does the driver know that there is no longer any code running (in `submit_bio` or in the `bio_end_io` functions) that might access the `gendisk` or metadata struct (free'd by `kfree(brd)` in the example above).

I see that `del_gendisk` et. al. freeze the queue and don't allow any more `I/O`, but from perusing the source it seems like this just stop new submissions to `submit_bio`. It does not track anything past the actual `submit_bio` call.

The `_disk` cleanup functions probably block until all open file handles to the device or its partitions are closed. Where is that code?

Answer (score 0):

`blkdev_close` is the higher level call which waits for all outstanding I/O. It calls `__sync_blockdev` to get everything written out.  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.20.17/source/fs/block_dev.c#L457

Comment: That seems like what is called when a process closes a previously opened block device. I can't see where the device cleanup code call `.release` -> `blkdev_close` on all open files. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Other way around. You can't remove a driver when the reference count on the device is non-zero. blkdev_get (open) increments the reference count. If nothing has the device, then you are free to remove the driver.

Comment: I think what you mean is that the `fops->owner` member is set to the module of the driver, and `blkdev_get` does a `try_module_get` on that, preventing the module from being unloaded (so, for example, `brd_cleanup` will never run until all handles are closed). Does this mean that drivers that allow removal of a specific device without unloading the module, must keep track of inflight i/o themselves; or is there some other code in `del_gendisk` that waits synchronously until some refcount reaches 0 - where is that code?

Comment: blkdev_put calls release when bd_openers gets to 0.

Comment: But a regular `blkdev_put` would be async. If `del_gendisk` etc. would call `blkdev_put` while the device is open, it would return immediately, leaving the handle open (only to be released when the handle is closed). When `kfree` is called on the disk, the open handle might still access the disk struct.